# PDO SQL Statement Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been looking at this for the last hour and cannot see why this wont work? It is carried out in a bootstrap modal via AJAX.

For some reason SupplierUpdate will not get updated in the database. (It is a timestamp)

```
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$username;charset=utf8", $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = "UPDATE Suppliers SET UpdateTime=:UpdateTime, Code1=:Code1, Code1Desc=:Code1Desc, Code2=:Code2, Code2Desc=:Code2Desc, Code3=:Code3, Code3Desc=:Code3Desc WHERE UserID ='$UserID'";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':Code1', $_POST['Code1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Code1Desc', $_POST['Code1Desc'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':Code2', $_POST['Code2'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':Code2Desc', $_POST['Code2Desc'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':Code3', $_POST['Code3'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':Code3Desc', $_POST['Code3Desc'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':UpdateTime', $_POST['Update'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

<input type="text" name="SupplierUpdate" id="SupplierUpdate" value="<?php echo $timestamp ?>">
```

Comment: Can you post any error output?  Are you saying that the other columns _do_ get updated but not `SupplierUpdate`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There are no errors from what I can see upon ctrl + shift + i

Comment: Great that you are using prepared statements but why are you still injecting `$UserID` in your query? You should bind that as well. And where does the value come from, can you confirm it is correct?

Comment: @Frog82 To see if there are errors in the query execution use a try catch loop that will help you to print the returned error.

Comment: @jeroen the value comes from     $date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);  and I should ideally be binding that value looking back at it

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have a try catch already in place, just forgot to show it within the code snippet         catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $conn = null;

Comment: @Frog82 I don't know what the format of your `UpdateTime` column is, but if it is `datetime` you don't need to calculate it, you can set it directly in mysql: `SET UpdateTime=NOW(), ...`. And I was talking about `$UserID`.

Comment: @jeroen $userID is indeed working because the other fields are updating

Comment: @Frog82 What is the format of the field `UpdateTime`? You should validate the `$_POST` variable to make sure the format is correct.

Comment: @jeroen for example, it currently displays 1433323848, however regardless of the format, it is not letting me add any value

Comment: @Frog82 add `echo $stmt->queryString` to the end after `execute()`. What is the output?

Comment: Also, just as a point of potential confusion, you've said to us that `SupplierUpdate` is not changing, but that field is not mentioned in the query. Then in the query the field is called `UpdateTime` but the POST param is called `Update`. Might be helpful to ensure all these names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your input type name="SupplierUpdate"
But i dont see you are binding it with this name
you are using $_POST['Update']

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was changing the variable names within SO text editor and missed it out

Comment: @Frog82 So is your problem merely a typo in your own code?

Comment: @Frog82 You should check an answer you like or atleast post your solution that you got. So that others wont have to waste time finding the problem and solution when there is none.

Answer (score -1):

you may try to debug it like below...

```
if($conn){
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
}
else{
echo "not connected";
}
```

Then, set your date format forcefully like,
    $upd_tim = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Update'])); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':UpdateTime', $upd_tim, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Then, after the execute(),

```
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```